# Using multiple databases for the same model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am working on some APIs that needs to connect to two separate database, containing similar tables but different data.

I have configurated the two datasources in my `app.php` and `app_local.php`, and both of them are reachable.

With a bit of research I have found that `ConnectionManager::alias` should be what I need, so I came up with this:

```
// Fetching `energy` DB data
ConnectionManager::alias('energy', 'default');
$energy = $this->Users->find()->first();
debug($energy);
ConnectionManager::dropAlias('default');

// Fetching `default` (gas) DB data
$gas = $this->Users->find()->first();
debug($gas);
```

The problem is that if I run those those queries like this the debug gives the same data, meaning that the data from the `energy` database is printed two times.

But:

- If I only run the `energy` find it gives me the correct results from the energy database.
- If I only run the `gas` find it gives me the correct results from the gas database.

It looks like only the first datasource is actually used.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The problem with what you're doing there aside, are you aware that aliasing the `default` connection will affect all other tables (include associations) that use the `default` connection too? Is that what you want, or do you explicitly only want to change the connection for `UsersTable` and nothing else (not even associations of `UsersTable`)?

Comment: That's actually what I want: when I "switch" to the secondary database, I want to completely (momentarily) replace the `default` db. Until I drop the alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a table class has been instantiated, it will hold the connection instance that was assigned to it when it was instantiated (`connection` option for `\Cake\ORM\Table::__construct()`), respectively the one that was created when the table first tried to obtain the connection (`\Cake\ORM\Table::getConnection()`).

So dropping the alias alone won't do anything, the next call on the table will use the connection instance that the table already holds, it will not attempt to obtain a connection again on its own.

Since you want the connection change to affect everything, you will have to clear the table registry after dropping the connection alias, and load the tables again, so that that they will be created again with the actual `default` connection (if you wanted to affect only specific instance, you could've assigned a new connection instance via `setConnection()`). To avoid running into the same problem with already created table instances when *creating* the alias, you should most probably also clear the registry after *that*.

Basic example:

```php
ConnectionManager::alias('energy', 'default');
$this->getTableLocator()->clear();
// table instances created after this point will respect the alias

$this->Users = null;
$this->loadModel('Users');
$energy = $this->Users->find()->first();

ConnectionManager::dropAlias('default');
$this->getTableLocator()->clear();
// table instances created after this point will use the non-aliased connection

$this->Users = null;
$this->loadModel('Users');
$gas = $this->Users->find()->first();
```

As you can see, this not only requires loading the model/table again, but also to unset the instance on the property, as otherwise `loadModel()` will not actually load the table again, but instead return the instance that is already set on the `$this->Users` property.

I would suggest that you switch to obtaining your models via the table locator, even in your controller, that way you can skip this awkward unset stuff, and you reduce the risk of accidentally accessing old instances stored on properties like `$this->Users`:

```php
ConnectionManager::alias('energy', 'default');
$this->getTableLocator()->clear();

$energy = $this->getTableLocator()-get('Users')->find()->first();

ConnectionManager::dropAlias('default');
$this->getTableLocator()->clear();

$gas = $this->getTableLocator()-get('Users')->find()->first();
```

You should probably also consider centralizing this connection switching somewhere in a service.

Comment: The second method works perfectly, thanks! For some reason the first method seems to be not working, but I didn't investigate much as it's not your suggested solution. By centralizing in a service do you mean a component?

Btw I think this could be a nice addition to the documentation, as there are a few (outdated) questions on SO for similar issues.

Comment: @ToX82 Ah sorry, I mentioned the problem with the stored reference, but forgot to reflect that in the code (that's exactly why using the locator is the better approach ;)). You'd have to reassign or unset `$this->Users`, as `loadModel()` will return the existing instance on that property in case it exists, respectively it will not overwrite the property if it's already set. I've updated the example.